# How to sort tuples with floats using "isclose" comparisons rather than absolute equality (==) in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, floating-point

I want to sort a list of pairs primarily by a float, and secondarily by an integer. The problem is with comparing floats for equality--in many cases we get an arbitrary comparison instead of resorting to the secondary order.

## Example

```
my_list = [
  (0, 1.2),
  (2, 0.07076863960397783),
  (1, 0.07076863960397785),
  (4, 0.02)
]
```

I want to sort primarily by the float values, and secondarily by the integers.
Running `sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))` returns this:

```
[(4, 0.02), (2, 0.07076863960397783), (1, 0.07076863960397785), (0, 1.2)]
```

But since the two floats are so close that they should really be considered equal, the desired order is this:

```
[(4, 0.02), (1, 0.07076863960397785), (2, 0.07076863960397783), (0, 1.2)]
```

How do I incorporate `math.isclose` or `np.isclose` into the sorting?

## My attempt

My current approach is to wrap the floats into a class that performs the comparisons using the numpy's `isclose`.

```
class FloatComparisonWrapper:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.value = num

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.__ne__(other) and self.value < other.value

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.__ne__(other) and self.value > other.value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return np.isclose(self.value, other.value)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.__eq__(other) or self.value <= other.value

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.__eq__(other) or self.value >= other.value
```

And then `sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (FloatComparisonWrapper(x[1]), x[0]))` gives the correct ordering.

Is this a good solution? Is it pythonic? Is it the best solution? Is there a quicker way to do it?

Comment: Just round to desired precision: `sorted(my_list, key=lambda t: (round(t[1],6),t[0]))`

Comment: Rounding a float does not solve the floating point equality comparison problem—it can that you get something like `round(0.123456789123, 6)` to be `0.123457000001`, right?

Comment: If you are not comfortable with `round` you can truncate: `sorted(my_list, key=lambda t: (int(t[1]*1e6),t[0]))` Any interpretation of a float involves compromise. If you round or truncate the near-equal floats, that *does* satisfy the need for total order. If you use `isclose` you may have the issue of asymmetry.

Comment: I am not sure how `round` is implemented and whether it can yield different floats as I wrote above--if it could, it solves nothing in the issue. Truncation is very much non-scalable like this. The orders of magnitude of my floats can differ significantly. So overall I think `isclose` would still win over these two solutions. But perhaps I need to write down my situation in more details as there might be no good general solutions for the problem abstraction as phrased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a good solution?

No.
OP's approach is flawed for sorting purposes.

> since the two floats are so close that they should really be considered equal

Consider if all values are nearly in the vicinity of of the same floating point value.  Some pairs are "equal", other not. OP's goal fails as the compare does not form a [Total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order).

---

From a C point-of-view that may apply to Python as I see the issue is language agnostic.

This will not work as `compare(a, b)`, `compare(b,c)`, `compare(a,c)` must form a consistent order.

> When the same objects (consisting of size bytes, irrespective of their current positions in the array) are passed more than once to the comparison function, the results shall be consistent with one another. That is, for qsort they shall define a total ordering on the array, ... C1723 § 7.24.5 4.

Consider

```
(2, float_before(x)), // Lowest value that "is close" to x.
(1, x),
(0, float_after(x)), // Greatest value that "is close" to x.
```

Even though `float_before(x)` and `x` are consecutive "equal" values, as proposed by OP, (as well as `x`, `float_after(x)`), the sorting will arrive at different (and possible inconclusive: e.g. infinite loop) results, depending on the order the compares are applied since `compare(float_before(x), float_after(x))` are not equal.

---

A secondary compare should not be applied unless the first order values are equal.  Nearly equal is insufficient as `a ≈ b` and `b ≈ c` may be true, but `a ≈ c`is not.

With OP's nearly equal, `a > b` and `b > c` due their primary compares are *equal*, but the secondary makes them greater than ordered, and implies `a > c`.  Yet since `a` is not close to `c` and the primary ordering is `a < c`.  This contradicts  `a > c`.

---

> Is there a quicker way to do it?

I recommend to drop the `isclose()` "two floats are so close that they should really be considered equal" approach for the primary compare. Simply do a value compare. Get the functionality correct before attempting to make it faster.

```
// Pseudo code
if (primary_compare_as_equal(a,b))
  return secondary compare(a,b)
return primary_compare(a,b)
```

Comment: This is a very good point, and an important thing to keep in mind. But your proposed solution is just wrong—it is what the first sorting call in my example does, and it gives *wrong* ordering. It's not only a wishful thinking for the two floats to be the same, they are really supposed to be the same. The only reason they differ is that the floating point arithmetics is how it is.

Comment: @OnDraganov In _general_, the goal you seek is unobtainable. It may be OK with the your select 4 sample example, but it does not extend to general sets of values.  Consider a set: a:(2, 0.07076863960397783), b:(1, 0.07076863960397785), c:(0, 0.07076863960397787), where 0.07076863960397787 is close to 0.07076863960397785, but not close to 0.07076863960397783.  You have, per your compare, a > b, b > c, yet c > a.

Comment: I know, I understand your point and agree that this is ill-defined *in general* (and probably a valid reason for why there is not an out-of-the-box solution for this). But in my application keeping the order according to the actual float comparison leads to a completely wrong result further down (which is how I got to this question in the first place). I guess the options are 1) change the way the floats are generated, 2) verify some extra assumptions so that this is ok, 3) have a different method using some extra information (my secondary order is not integers, but inclusion partial relation)

Comment: @OnDraganov Perhaps (another) post with details about the problem you are having, since the approach used here to solve it has weaknesses?

Comment: Yeah, I agree that my problem might have a good solution even if the generality written here does not. What I really have is pairs `(float, set)`, and I *think* that all I really need is to ensure that subsets come before sets in the resulting order. I think that two-round sorting should work: first run just sort with floats, second run sort with inclusion relation. Then *in Python 3* the second run should only do a minimal amount of swaps to ensure the compatibility with the inclusion relation, and leave the rest. Should I create a new question and link them together as related?

Comment: @OnDraganov Suggest to learn what you can from this Q and post another.  Reference this post in that with a clear different question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cmp_to_key` from functools to implement the comparison with math.isclose:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key
from math import isclose

my_list.sort(key=cmp_to_key(lambda a,b: not isclose(a[1],b[1]) and a[1]-b[1]
                                        or a[0]-b[0]))

print(my_list)
[(4, 0.02), (1, 0.07076863960397785), (2, 0.07076863960397783), (0, 1.2)]
```

If you're going for a comparison class, I would suggest basing it on `float` and minimizing the number of indirections (function call levels):

```
from math import isclose

class FloatCompare(float):
     def __lt__(self,other): 
          return float.__lt__(self,other) and not isclose(self,other)    
    
my_list.sort(key=lambda x:(FloatCompare(x[1]),x[0]))

print(my_list)

[(4, 0.02), (1, 0.07076863960397785), (2, 0.07076863960397783), (0, 1.2)]
```

*Note that you can define all the comparison methods but sort() only actually uses `__lt__` ([list.sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort))*

Comment: I stumbled on `cmp_to_key`, but isn't it discouraged to use it now, as it is there just for backward compatibility with Python 2 solutions?

Comment: It is obviously not a good idea in cases where a simple key function can be used.  But for topological sorts and situations such as yours where a simple key function cannot be used, it does the same thing as creating a comparison wrapper (without the extra hassle of creating your own class).  I couldn't find documentation that says it is "discouraged" or strictly limited to Python 2 conversion.

Comment: Right, I got the "discouragement" idea originally from a different question here on stackoverflow, which I cannot find anymore. The official docs say "This function is primarily used as a transition tool for programs being converted from Python 2 which supported the use of comparison functions." -- I guess it is up to interpretation and taste to decide whether this is a discouragement to use it in other cases or not. The way you write it is beautifully concise though. I did not realise that any negative or any positive is as good as -1 or 1, respectively, and that False is as good as 0 here.

Comment: False is never actually returned (although it is indeed equivalent to zero).  BTW if your second comparison isn't numerical, a nice way to obtain the -1,0,1 value is to express it like this:  `(a[0]>b[0]) - (a[0]<b[0])`

Answer (score -1):

Slightly more Pythonic would be to take advantage of [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) to reduce `FloatComparisonWrapper` down to the following:

```py
@functools.total_ordering
class FloatComparisonWrapper:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.value = num

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.__eq__(other) or self.value < other.value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return np.isclose(self.value, other.value)
```

Whether this solution is good or the best is a matter of opinion and whether it's fastest doesn't matter if it's fast enough.

Comment: Does `__lt__` with that decorator by default first check for `not __eq__(...)`?

Comment: I don't see where it's specified either way. You can implement `__le__` instead which should cover the concern. Edited to show.